# telerik angular kendo for angular 2 datepicker displays wrong date

Tags: datepicker, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying with the telerik kendo ui for angular 2 (http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/)

working on the datepicker, don't know why it looks like the datepicker adds one month to the binding value. As you see it in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/8yUqiagcZ957saufxYpS?p=preview

The date is set to `new Date(2000, 2, 10);` but the control displays 03/10/2000.
I want it displays exactly as set( e.g 02/10/2000). How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript Date object accepts zero-based month values, unlike the days and years for instance.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

That being said, just pass `1` to display "February".

```
new Date(2000, 1, 10)
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pb09ZPo4L18ExGYOcu4x?p=preview